# docker-compose psql does not serve on 127.0.0.1

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psql

### Problem:

I am trying to server postgres container with the database on it, whenever I boot up the container, the postgres is server or a random address ex. 172.12.0.1 etc. I need it to always server on localhost.

### What I've tried

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    build:
      args:
        user: admin
        uid: 1000
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: platform
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
      - DB_HOST= db
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_DATABASE=database
      - DB_USERNAME=username
    depends_on:
      - db
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - nginx

  db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
        - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_DATABASE}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./db1:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db1
      - ./docker-compose/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - nginx

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker-compose/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - nginx
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db 

networks:
  nginx:
    driver: bridge
```

Whenever I start up my docker-compose file, the database container should build and serve to localhost at post 5432. that should be accessible on the app container

Comment: docker container dont find each other with localhost. As far as it seems you did already do it correct by using the database *service* name has hostname in your app container environment. Only issue I see is an extra whitespace there. You have also published the database ports, that way it will be accessible on the host via localhost and potentially everyone that can reach your host system. If it's a server without proper firewall/iptables config, your database will be publicly accessible.

Comment: Thank you, what whitespace are you referring to?  So in the development app inside the .env file, I have to change the DB_HOST each time the host changes?

Comment: You set environment variables in the YAML file. One of them is called DB_HOST. That is the name of the DB service. But it has an extra space after the =. You are supposed to use this variable inside the container to get the service name and then resolve it against dockers DNS resolver. I personally would also remove those container names from the config, they are matching the service names, that's why it still works what I just said but actually to be precise,  container find each other via container name. If you don't set it explicitly, compose will use the service name as the container name.

Comment: You could technically hardcode the host name and use db. But using this variable has also the benefit of you are being able to change it later from outside while you dont have to change anything inside the container. Its a good practice to leverage environment variables for this kind of stuff. 12 factor app style.

Comment: If you insist on using an IP, there are ways to make the IP static in your compose setup, but I would not recommend it. ctrl+f for *ipam* in this document and you see what I mean. There is unfortunalty not a direct link in it for this https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/